# Expression vs. Statement (Javascript) In-Depth Overview

Tags: javascript

Okay, after thoroughly trying to research the subtle difference between javascript expressions and statements, I am still seeking a deeper understanding. I am aware that expressions can be used as statements because expressions evaluate to a value and so forth but I am simply interested in knowing **why** such is the case. Specifically I would like to have an explanation of **why** an if statement is distinct from a ternary operation.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=difference+between+javascript+expressions+and+statements&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN704IN704&oq=difference+between+javascript+expressions+and+statements&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Expressions evaluate into something, statement do things (while, for ,if). The if statement evaluates to nothing and thus can not be assigned to anything, while the ternary operation does evaluate into something and can be assigned. It is thus an expression

Answer (score 0):

in an if condition you don't have to write the else part, also you can choose to leave the block empty like below example

```
if(a==1){
//do nothing or do something its upto me
}else{
console.log(a);
}
```

while in ternary operation you have to provide both if and else part, so if you have both the operations to perform and they are one liner or single statement then go for ternary operations,

ternary operations are useful in case of assignment of values or returning values from functions